# Detailed axis and legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to put legend and more values in x limits.

```
test <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10), mean_y = 0.1) 
ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(color = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(x, mean_y))
```

Comment: Could you include a dataset, and other elements of a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1)?  Otherwise, checkout the [ggplot reference](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/) and Winston Chang's [cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

Comment: I insert a MWE.

Comment: What do you mean by "more values"? Like you want to change the limits on what's shown along the x axis, or you want more axis breaks? You don't have a legend because nothing is being mapped to any aesthetics that would show legends, such as fill, color, or linetype. You can use a dummy value to do that; there should be lots of other SO posts to show this

Comment: I'd like to show seq(0, 1, 0.1) in x limits.

Comment: So that would be the breaks in your `scale_x_continuous`. What would be in the legend? Like I said, there's nothing assigned to an aesthetic that creates a legend

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a bit more explanation and a reproducible example, but to get "more values in x limits" you can try adding

```
+ expand_limits(x = c(1, 1000))
```

Just replace the values in the vector by the ones that actually fit your needs.